# TypeError: SuppressChunksPlugin is not a constructor, how to overcome this is a webpack?

Tags: javascript, constructor, webpack, typeerror, webpack-plugin

```
  new SuppressChunksPlugin([
    ^
```

TypeError: SuppressChunksPlugin is not a constructor
    at Object. (/Users/rohit/WebstormProjects/myProjectStructure/webpack.config.js:80:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at requireConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:97:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:104:17

Below is the web config files.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var SuppressChunksPlugin = require('suppress-chunks-webpack-plugin');



module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  entry: {
        blitz: './blitz.js',


  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/assets'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'

    },


    module: {


       rules: [
            {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                // use style-loader in development
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: 'css-loader?minimize!less-loader'

              })
            },

           {
               test: /\.css$/,
               use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                   fallback: 'style-loader',
                   use:'css-loader?minimize'

               })
           }
       ]
    },
    plugins:[
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
        new SuppressChunksPlugin([
            {name: 'blitz', match: /\.js$/},

        ])
    ]
};
```

Comment: Can you post your webpack.config.js file?

Comment: Hi, have updated with the web config file as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `suppress-chunks-webpack-plugin` uses [ES modules and only has a default export](https://github.com/alxlu/suppress-chunks-webpack-plugin/blob/master/src/index.js#L8) (see also the transpiled source [unpkg - suppress-chunks-webpack-plugin](https://unpkg.com/suppress-chunks-webpack-plugin@0.0.4/dist/index.js)).

To use it with Node's `require` you need to access the `default` property.

```
var SuppressChunksPlugin = require('suppress-chunks-webpack-plugin').default;
```

Comment: Finally it worked with default export, thank you very much.